# How do i build and deploy an API service in Liferay 7.4 with gradle?

Tags: api, gradle, service, liferay-7

*Gradle buildService not working correctly in Liferay 7.4*

Hi all,

I'm trying to deploy a simple API service in Liferay framework with gradle but it seems it's not building packages correctly.
After I execute buildService, I try to deploy the service but I get this error:

error  : Exporting an empty package 'com.test.exception'

[this is how gradle is currently building directories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J67AL.png)

This is how I think packages' directories should be built in order to successfully deploy:

```
|->apiService

||->main

||||->java

||||||->com.testService.exception

||||||->com.testservice.model

||||||->com.testService.service
```

Answer (score 0):

Please update settings.gradle, update gradle plugin liferay workspace version to 4.0.22 and retry.

```
classpath(group: "com.liferay", name: "com.liferay.gradle.plugins.workspace", version: "4.0.22")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).